# TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType) singly linked list

Tags: python, typeerror, singly-linked-list

So im trying to print out the data part of my singly linked list and keep getting this error

> TypeError: **str** returned non-string (type NoneType)

The node class:

```
class Node:
    """ Node class """

    def __init__(self, data, next_node=None):
        """ initializes private variable data"""
        self.__data = data
        self.__next_node = next_node

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self.__data

    @data.setter
    def data(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise TypeError("data must be integer")
        self.__data = value

    @property
    def next_node(self):
        return self.__next_node

    @next_node.setter
    def next_node(self, value):
        if value != None and not isinstance(value, Node):
            raise TypeError("next_node must be a Node object")
        self.__next_node = value
```

and the singly linked list class:

```
class SinglyLinkedList:
    """creates a sorted linked list"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.__head = Node(0)

    def __repr__(self):

        while True:
            print(self.__head.data)
            if (self.__head.next_node == None):
                break
            else:
                self.__head = self.__head.next_node

    def sorted_insert(self, value):
        new_node = Node(value)
        if self.__head.next_node == None and self.__head.data == 0:
            self.__head = new_node
        else:
            save_head = Node(0)
            save_head = self.__head
            if self.__head.data < value:
                while int(self.__head.data) <= int(value):
                    if self.__head.next_node != None:
                        if self.__head.next_node.data >= value:
                            new_node.next_node = self.__head.next_node
                            self.__head.next_node = new_node
                            break
                    if self.__head.next_node == None:
                        self.__head.next_node = new_node
                        break
                    self.__head = self.__head.next_node
                self.__head = save_head
            elif self.__head.data > value:
                new_node.next_node = self.__head
                self.__head = new_node
```

and main function:

```
class Main:
    def main():
        sll = SinglyLinkedList()
        sll.sorted_insert(2)
        sll.sorted_insert(5)
        sll.sorted_insert(3)
        sll.sorted_insert(10)
        sll.sorted_insert(1)
        sll.sorted_insert(-4)
        sll.sorted_insert(-3)
        sll.sorted_insert(4)
        sll.sorted_insert(5)
        sll.sorted_insert(12)
        sll.sorted_insert(3)
        print(sll)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Printing the list works just fine but i get an error after the printing is done which i reckon has something to do with me trying to print a non existent node in the linked list but i can't figure out where this extra addition is happening or if the ****repr**** function runs more rounds than it should.

Comment: The repr/str special methods must *return* a formatted string. Printing these strings is not their responsibility.

Comment: What do you suggest i do @MisterMiyagi

Comment: Your `__repr__` method must return a string. It currently does t have a return statement, so it returns `None` by default. Note, it shouldn't print anything

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- The error is caused by the fact that you implemented `__repr__` wrongly: it should *not* print, but instead return a string.
- Your loop alters `self.__head`, which means that you *loose* nodes. `self.__head` should remain put where it is: referencing the *first* node in the list, and not any other node.
- The list is initialised with a dummy node that has value 0. But 0 is not some magical value... it could be that you actually insert 0 later on, and then it is impossible to know whether that node is the dummy node or not. You should better not create a node at all when the linked list is constructed. Initialise `self.__head` with `None`
- `sorted_insert` is unnecessarily complicated. It also makes the error of moving `self.__head`, although its value is restored after the loop. But this is not best practice. There are also too many places where the value is compared with a node's value. That should just happen at one place.

For the purpose of `__repr__` I would suggest to first define an even more useful method: `__iter__`. Once you have that, it becomes quite simple to create the string in `__repr__`. The loop is then implemented in `__iter__`, while the string related stuff is present in `__repr__`.

Here is your `SinglyLinkedList` code with the above mentioned fixes applied:

```
class SinglyLinkedList:
    """creates a sorted linked list"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.__head = None  # Don't create a node yet! An empty list has no nodes

    def __iter__(self):  # Make a singly linked list iterable
        node = self.__head  # Use a variable for iteration. Don't move the head!!
        while node:  # Just check whether you still have a reference to a Node
            yield node.data
            node = node.next_node
        
    def __repr__(self):
        # Don't print in __repr__. Instead return a string.
        # Iterate `self` to get all the data, turn each data to string by calling `repr`
        #  on them, and finally join into one string, space-separated.
        return " ".join(map(repr, self))

    def sorted_insert(self, value):
        new_node = Node(value)
        prev = None
        node = self.__head
        while node and node.data < value:
            prev = node
            node = node.next_node
        if prev:
            prev.next_node = new_node
        else:
            self.__head = new_node
        new_node.next_node = node
```